# NFC makereadonly fails on some devices

Tags: android, nfc

I tried to make an NFC-Tag readonly. On different devices I get different results:

```
Samsung Galaxy Nexus returns for ndef.canMakeReadOnly():
true

Sony Xperia S returns for ndef.canMakeReadOnly():
false
```

It is the same tag, the same code. Without the check I get an error:

```
pphLibNfc_ConvertToReadOnlyNdef() returned 0x00ff [NFCSTATUS_FAILED]
```

Comment: What tag-technology are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are type- or vendor-specific ways of locking or unlocking tags, so in general you cannot expect them all to be present in all devices.